# Acer wireless is not working

Tags: wireless, acer

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer Travelmate 2300, and I can't enable wireless or use the wireless switch. Does anyone know how to turn on wifi on an Acer Travelmate 2300 using Ubuntu 12.04?

This is the first time I've tried to use Linux. I've always used Windows.

Comment: please post the output of `lspci | grep network`

Comment: I must be doing something wrong all I get is command not found

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Comment: Is there a way to do it though widows my usbs don't work (long story)sorry for not saying that earlier

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rcSiszBY

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to Internet via ethernet?

If yes, do so and go to dash and type **Additional Drivers**

This should open a window and hopefully you will find your Wireless card drivers listed

Click **Activate** and you are good to go

The window should look like this [image]

Comment: Nothing comes up when going into the additional drivers

Comment: Try to update your system while connected to Internet then recheck.

Comment: What is your Wireless card model?

Comment: I think its acer IPN2220 Wireless LAN Card

Comment: I checked and it isn't found in Ubuntu HCL. Hope you find answer with someone else.

Comment: Willing to provide an answer. Keep checking every while and I'll hopefully find and post you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ndiwrapper to get your device to work there is no native support for your wifi card in linux.

Download the windows driver to your desktop:
[winxp.zip](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=223428&d=1346360445)

Then:
Right click on the driver and select extract here. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk
sudo ndisgtk
```

A window will open, point to Desktop > Winxp > neti2220.inf. Your wireless should turn on.

Comment: I tried this but it says its the wrong driver.